# Is there a way to use default arguments that are the result of a function call in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, refactoring, option-type, optional-arguments

I have a whole slew of database access functions which assume a particular connection string.  Within my application I call

```
myList = DB_MyTable.GetTableItems()
```

and within `GetTableItems()` I have something like

```
Dim connection As SqlConnection = MyDB.GetConnection
```

So the connection string is in one place in the code, and I call a method to get it.

What I'm running into now is I want to reuse the same database functions, but with a different connection string.  I can rewrite all of the functions like `DB_MyTable.GetTableItems()` easily because they're generated from a script, but within the main application code I'll need to take care of every function call that now needs to know what connection string I want to use.

I tried changing the arguments to `GetTableItems()` like this:

```
Public Shared Function GetTableItems(Optional ByVal useThisString as String = MyDB.GetConnection) As List(Of MyItems)
```

in hopes of being able to pass in, by default, the string I'm already using in most of the code, but I got an error saying that the default value had to be a constant expression.  This would mean peppering a specific connection string everywhere, which I don't want to do.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm after, or do I need to make the connection string a required argument and change all of the calls in my application to match the new signature?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make your default value an empty string?  Then, in your functions, if the useThisString variable is blank, then use default, else use the one you passed in?  A littler dirtier, but just barely.

Comment: That did occur to me!  Maybe I shied away from it initially because every single call would have that check at the beginning, and it might be a performance drag.  But that would save me most of the work in retrofitting the existing code.